# Why do I keep getting Java.Lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, game-loop

I keep getting a Java.Lang.NullPointerException on this code:

```
private void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

Can someone tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If `bs` is null, do you expect some part of this code to make it not null?

Comment: this.createBufferStrategy(3);

Comment: @swingBoris: How do you expect that to change `bs`?

Comment: Which line throws it? Did you try to debug?

Answer (score 3):

Even when you call `this.createBufferStrategy(3);` your `bs` variable remains unassigned.

You need to read it back after creating it:

```
if(bs == null){
    this.createBufferStrategy(3);
    bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
}
```

It is a good idea to add a check to make sure that after the call of `createBufferStrategy` you get back a non-null:

```
this.createBufferStrategy(3);
bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
if (bs == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Buffered structure is not created.");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
private void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        bs = this.getBufferStrategy(); // reassign bs
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

Comment: [`createBufferStrategy` returns void](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#createBufferStrategy%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

You forget to assign the new BufferStrategy in case it was `null` to the to variable bs. Change it to

```
if (bs == null) {
    bs = this.createBufferStrategy(3); // in case it returns BufferStrategy.
    bs = this.getBufferStrategy(); // otherwise
}
```

Answer (score 0):

owww i am so stupid i forgot to put return it should be this

```
private void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```